# Error when brewing Qt 32 bits on OS X

Tags: macos, qt, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

When trying to install Qt on OSX (10.11) via homebrew with the `--universal` option

```
brew install qt --universal
```

I get the following error:

```
clang: error: invalid Xarch argument: '-Xarch_i386 -framework', options requiring arguments are unsupported
clang: error: invalid Xarch argument: '-Xarch_i386 -framework', options requiring arguments are unsupported
make[4]: *** [../../../../plugins/phonon_backend/libphonon_qt7.dylib] Error 1
make[3]: *** [release] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-qt7-make_default] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-phonon-make_default] Error 2
make: *** [sub-plugins-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: What is the output of `brew gist-logs qt`?

Comment: @bfontaine https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8b7e9606234cef0496fb